# How to extract only the capture group in a regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract a pattern from some html. I am using stringr.

I have a list of numbers such as `nums<-c(">00324R<",">E223143<",">00000F<")`
 I have tried `str_extract(nums,">[A-Z0-9]{4,}?<")` which extracts the pattern I want(  `">00324R<"  ">E223143<" ">00000F<"` ) but I don't want to extract < or >

I am aware that positive lookahead may be the answer here but I don't seem to be able to create one that works and I'm not sure why not. I have tried:

```
str_extract(nums,"(?<=<)[A-Z0-9]{4,}?<")
```

Comment: any issues with `gsub("[<>]", "", nums)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex

```
> str_extract(nums,"(?<=>)[A-Z0-9]{4,}(?=<)")
[1] "00324R"  "E223143" "00000F"
```

**Details**

- `(?<=>)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `>`
- `[A-Z0-9]{4,}` - four or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `(?=<)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `<`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jEWcOk/1) and the regex graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are so consistent, you could just select anything that is not `>` or `<`:

```
str_extract(nums, "[^<>]+")
# [1] "00324R"  "E223143" "00000F"
```

Or `gsub()` them away:

```
gsub("[<|>]", "", nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove "<" or ">" as follows:

gsub("[<| >]", ''", nums)